# Function on a set - $(a,b)↦\frac{2ab}{a+b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Lets define a function which replaces two elements $a,b$ of a set $$1,\frac{1}{2},\dots,\frac{1}{64}$$
with: $$\frac{2ab}{a+b}$$

What must all elements be if after a number of steps all elements are equal?

My effort:
If all elements are equal, then $a=b$, when the function will be applied they'll be replaced by $\frac{2a^2}{2a}=a$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that even if we take $\frac{2ab}{a+b}$, $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{a+b}{2ab}+\frac{a+b}{2ab}$$

Thus, the sum of their reciprocals must be equal, no matter how much we change them.

Let me clarify this with a example. Imagine there was $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}$. We use the same operation that you described- for $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}$ we get $\frac{2}{5}, \frac{2}{5}$.

The sum of reciprocals before was $1+2+3=6$.

The sum of reciprocals now is $\frac{5}{2}+\frac{5}{2}+1=6$.

Comment: @MIkeB. Why did you unaccept?

Comment: @MikeB. Was my approach not satisfactory?